# What is the fundmental difference between MongoDB / NoSQL which allows faster aggregation (MapReduce) compared to MySQL

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

Greeting!

I have the following problem. I have a table with huge number of rows which I need to search and then group search results by many parameters. Let's say the table is

```
id, big_text, price, country, field1, field2, ..., fieldX
```

And we run a request like this

```
SELECT .... WHERE 
[use FULLTEXT index to MATCH() big_text] AND 
[use some random clauses that anyway render indexes useless, 
like: country IN (1,2,65,69) and price<100]
```

This we be displayed as search results and then we need to take these search results and group them by a number of fields to generate search filters

```
(results) GROUP BY field1
(results) GROUP BY field2
(results) GROUP BY field3
(results) GROUP BY field4
```

This is a simplified case of what I need, the actual task at hand is even more problematic, for example sometimes the first results query does also its own GROUP BY. And example of such functionality would be this site
http://www.indeed.com/q-sales-jobs.html
(search results plus filters on the left)

I've done and still doing a deep research on how MySQL functions and at this point I totally don't see this possible in MySQL. Roughly speaking MySQL table is just a heap of rows lying on HDD and indexes are tiny versions of these tables sorted by the index field(s) and pointing to the actual rows. That's a super oversimplification of course but the point is I don't see how it is possible to fix this at all, i.e. how to use more than one index, be able to do fast GROUP BY-s (by the time query reaches GROUP BY index is completely useless because of range searches and other things). I know that MySQL (or similar databases) have various helpful things such index merges, loose index scans and so on but this is simply not adequate - the queries above will still take forever to execute.

I was told that the problem can be solved by NoSQL which makes use of some radically new ways of storing and dealing with data, including aggregation tasks. What I want to know is some quick schematic explanation of how it does this. I mean I just want to have a quick glimpse at it so that I could really see that it does that because at the moment I can't understand how it is possible to do that at all. I mean data is still data and has to be placed in memory and indexes are still indexes with all their limitation. If this is indeed possible, I'll then start studying NoSQL in detail.

PS. Please don't tell me to go and read a big book on NoSQL. I've already done this for MySQL only to find out that it is not usable in my case :) So I wanted to have some preliminary understanding of the technology before getting a big book.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are essentially 4 types of "NoSQL", but three of the four are actually similar enough that an SQL syntax could be written on top of it (including MongoDB and it's crazy query syntax [and I say that even though Javascript is one of my favorite languages]).

### Key-Value Storage

These are simple NoSQL systems like Redis, that are basically a really fancy hash table. You have a value you want to get later, so you assign it a key and stuff it into the database, you can only query a single object at a time and only by a single key.

You definitely don't want this.

### Document Storage

This is one step up above Key-Value Storage and is what most people talk about when they say NoSQL (such as MongoDB).

Basically, these are objects with a hierarchical structure (like XML files, JSON files, and any other sort of tree structure in computer science), but the values of different nodes on the tree can be indexed. They have a higher "speed" relative to traditional row-based SQL databases on lookup because they sacrifice performance on joining.

If you're looking up data in your MySQL database from a single table with tons of columns (assuming it's not a view/virtual table), and assuming you have it indexed properly for your query (that may be you real problem, here), Document Databases like MongoDB won't give you any Big-O benefit over MySQL, so you probably don't want to migrate over for just this reason.

### Columnar Storage

These are the most like SQL databases. In fact, some (like Sybase) implement an SQL syntax while others (Cassandra) do not. They store the data in columns rather than rows, so adding and updating are expensive, but most queries are cheap because each column is essentially implicitly indexed.

But, if your query can't use an index, you're in no better shape with a Columnar Store than a regular SQL database.

### Graph Storage

Graph Databases expand *beyond* SQL. Anything that can be represented by Graph theory, including Key-Value, Document Database, and SQL database can be represented by a Graph Database, like neo4j.

Graph Databases make joins as cheap as possible (as opposed to Document Databases) to do this, but they have to, because even a simple "row" query would require many joins to retrieve.

A table-scan type query would *probably* be slower than a standard SQL database because of all of the extra joins to retrieve the data (which is stored in a disjointed fashion).

### So what's the solution?

You've probably noticed that I haven't answered your question, exactly. I'm not saying "you're finished," but the real problem is how the query is being performed.

1. Are you absolutely sure you can't better index your data? There are things such as [Multiple Column Keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) that could improve the performance of your particular query. Microsoft's SQL Server has a [full text key type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx) that would be applicable to the example you provided, and [PostgreSQL can emulate it](http://www.devx.com/opensource/Article/21674/1954).
2. The *real* advantage most NoSQL databases have over SQL databases is Map-Reduce -- specifically, the integration of a full Turing-complete language that runs at high speed that query constraints can be written in. The querying function can be written to quickly "fail out" of non-matching queries or quickly return with a success on records that meet "priority" requirements, while doing the same in SQL is a bit more cumbersome.

Finally, however, the exact problem you're trying to solve: text search with optional filtering parameters, is more generally known as a `search engine`, and there are very specialized engines to handle this particular problem. I'd recommend [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) to perform these queries.

Basically, dump the text field, the "filter" fields, and the primary key of the table into Solr, let it index the text field, run the queries through it, and if you need the full record after that, query your SQL database for the specific index you got from Solr. It uses some more memory and requires a second process, but will probably best suite your needs, here.

### Why all of this text to get to this answer?

Because the title of your question doesn't really have anything to do with the content of your question, so I answered both. :)